# How to intercept HOME button similar to Nova Launcher?

Tags: android, kiosk, android-homebutton

I have a requirement to make a kiosk application and I need to handle HOME button and change the behavior of my application. 
My application is already a launcher app but I need to consume the HOME button.

I see that Nova Launcher is doing a similar thing, they have added custom actions on click of HOME button. 
Does anyone know how are they doing it?